# KaptContext cannot access Context

Tags: android, kotlin, fastlane

I want to integrate `fastlane` into my project. I have set up all the basic stuff and now I want to deploy my project to beta release. I run `fastlane android beta` and get below error. 
If I compile with Android Studio 3.1 everything works fine.

```
:app:kaptGenerateStubsReleaseKotline: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.KaptContext (in unnamed module @0x253fbddb) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.util to unnamed module @0x253fbddb
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.KaptContext.<init>(KaptContext.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.compileStubs(Kapt3Extension.kt:265)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.generateStubs(Kapt3Extension.kt:215)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:178)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:97)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:107)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:84)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:374)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:64)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:365)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:130)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:161)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:63)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:108)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:451)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:97)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:218)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.access$compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:37)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner$compile$2.invoke(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:80)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:527)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:97)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:408)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:97)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:909)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:97)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:939)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:908)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:407)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.base@9-internal/Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-internal/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-internal/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@9-internal/Method.java:531)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(java.rmi@9-internal/UnicastServerRef.java:321)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(java.rmi@9-internal/Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(java.rmi@9-internal/Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(java.base@9-internal/Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(java.rmi@9-internal/Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(java.rmi@9-internal/TCPTransport.java:563)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(java.rmi@9-internal/TCPTransport.java:821)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(java.rmi@9-internal/TCPTransport.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(java.base@9-internal/Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(java.rmi@9-internal/TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@9-internal/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1158)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@9-internal/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:632)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@9-internal/Thread.java:804)

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsReleaseKotlin'.
> Internal compiler error. See log for more details
```

Gradle Dependencies

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.31'
ext.daggerVersion = '2.7'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion"
```

Any idea what might be wrong here?

Comment: For me I was using Mac M1 the following answer helped https://stackoverflow.com/a/71319188/2768515

Answer (score 0):

when I have updated Gradle this nothing-saying error changed to proper one - the issue was that Google database Room dependency hadn't had proper cerificate and I needed to change openjdk9 to openjdk8 (I am using Ubuntu), then error disappeared